# How to right-align section numbering in a memoir Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir

I'd like to right-align the section numbers in the Table of Contents of a `memoir` document. I'm already using some `tocloft` features and figured it would have this feature, but I can't seem to find it. Is this possible, preferably using a feature that `memoir` already provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers for `\section`s inside [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s ToC is set inside a box of with `\cftsectionnumwidth`. Since it's placed inside a fixed-width box, we can insert `\hfill` at the start (thereby pushing the number to the right of the box) and insert a space at the end (to separate it from the remaining ToC entry title):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{3.5em}% Width of \section numbers in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpresnum}{\hfill}% Inserted before \section numbers in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnum}{\quad}% Inserts after \section numbers in ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\setcounter{section}{9}% For this example
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

You may also want to adjust the width of the box to suit your needs. I've adjusted it to be `3.5em` wide with a `\quad` (or `1em`) space at the end.

Don't load [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) with `memoir` as it provides it own ToC-related settings that is very similar in nature to what `tocloft` provides.