# Memoir ToC: indent the second line by number+space width in the previous line OR set standard spacing OR right alignment in the box with the number

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, indentation

How can I achieve the following simple ToC in memoir?

```
    Introduction
       0.1. First section
    1. First chapter
       1.1. First section
            1.1.1. First subsection
    12. 12th chapter
        12.1. First section
              12.1.1. First subsection
```

It's better to avoid using extra packages.

```
    \documentclass{memoir}
    %% delete boxes
    \renewcommand\numberlinebox[2]{#2} % for sections
    \renewcommand\chapternumberlinebox[2]{#2} % for chapters 
    %% set dot and space
    \renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnum{.\space} 
    \renewcommand\cftsectionaftersnum{.\space}        \renewcommand\cftsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}     \renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}  
    %%enumeration levels in the ToC and text
    \settocdepth{subsection} 
    \setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
    \setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil} %hyphenation is forbidden

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \setcounter{chapter}{11}
    \chapter{Another chapter long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \subsection*{Short conclusion with long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{susubsection}{Short conclusion}
    \end{document}
```

PDF

[image]

**UDT1** Very close effect to the simplest ToC, that I need, can be achieved by the `boxed` approach.

**How can I replace all `\quad` spacing between the number and the title by standard `\space`?**

Perhaps, replacing of `\hfil` from right side of the boxes to the left sides would lead to the desirable effect.

Related question:
[How to right-align section numbering in a memoir Table of Contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289267/how-to-right-align-section-numbering-in-a-memoir-table-of-contents)

**UDT2**

The 0.1 subsection in Introduction should be indented as the 1.1 subsection.

If you want to take into accout UPD3, follow @Werner's suggestion to use the following code instead of using `etoolbox`:

```
    \renewcommand{\mempreaddchaptertotochook}{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{%
            \protect\settowidth{\protect\cftchapternumwidth}{\cftchapterfont \thechapter.\space}%
            \protect\setlength{\protect\cftsectionindent}{\protect\cftchapternumwidth}%
        }%
    }

    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter

    \xpatchcmd{\@m@mschapter}% <cmd>
    {\@schapter}% <search>
    {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\settowidth{\protect\cftsectionindent}{\protect\cftchapterfont \thechapter.\space}}%
        \@schapter}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>

    \patchcmd{\M@sect}% <cmd>
    {\addcontentsline}% <search>
    {\addtocontents{toc}{%
            \protect\settowidth{\csname cft#1numwidth\endcsname}{\csname cft#1font\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname.\space}%
            \protect\setlength{\csname cftsub#1indent\endcsname}{\protect\dimexpr\csname cft#1numwidth\endcsname+\csname cft#1indent\endcsname}%
        }%
        \addcontentsline}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
    \makeatother
```

**UPD3**

If you try to replace some commands, the output can be unpredictable!

Many thanks to @Werner and @jfbu!

Comment: Well, when you are not using boxed numberlines, the indentations will depend on the current number and thus not really something we can handle (unless you really start doing some internal reprogramming). IMO it will also look very uneven.

Comment: @daleif, thank you for the message once again =). The numberlines can be used to obtain the result. I've already tried `\cftsetindents{subsection}{\cftsectionindent+\parindent}{0em}` etc, however with no good results. Currently, I'm going to try these approaches: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306857/44348 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40032/44348

Comment: Simply removing all your strange `\renewcommand`'s achieve what you seem to be aiming at.

Comment: @jfbu, removing all `\renewcommand`'s will lead to the basic output. It is very close to the desirable ToC. However, I think that if in the `boxed` approach there could be (standard)`\space` instead of `\quad`, i.e. `\vfil` at the left side of the `box` it would be great. The question is updated.

Comment: @daleif, following your comment I decided to reformulate the question, please, take part in the discussion. How can I make right alignment in the box? Actually I need standard space instead of `\quad`, which seems to take place because of `\vfil` in the right side of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code adds to hooks for `\chapter` and (sub-)`\section`s to insert a spacing update directly into the ToC with every call to a sectional unit that writes to the ToC:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\mempreaddchaptertotochook}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\settowidth{\protect\cftchapternumwidth}{\cftchapterfont \thechapter.\space}%
    \protect\setlength{\protect\cftsectionindent}{\protect\cftchapternumwidth}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\M@sect}% <cmd>
  {\addcontentsline}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{toc}{%
     \protect\settowidth{\csname cft#1numwidth\endcsname}{\csname cft#1font\endcsname \csname the#1\endcsname.\space}%
     \protect\setlength{\csname cftsub#1indent\endcsname}{\protect\dimexpr\csname cft#1numwidth\endcsname+\csname cft#1indent\endcsname}%
   }%
   \addcontentsline}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

%% delete boxes
\renewcommand\numberlinebox[2]{#2} % for sections
\renewcommand\chapternumberlinebox[2]{#2} % for chapters 
%% set dot and space
\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnum{.\space} 
\renewcommand\cftsectionaftersnum{.\space}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}  

%%enumeration levels in the ToC and text
\settocdepth{subsection} 
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil} %hyphenation is forbidden

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}

\chapter{Another chapter long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection*{Short conclusion with long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Short conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Since the spacing is updated within the ToC, it takes at least two compilations for it to be updated correctly with any change in the ToC content.

Here's the `.toc` for the above code, highlighting how the content is inserted/updated:

```
\changetocdepth {2}
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{Introduction}{3}
\settowidth {\cftchapternumwidth }{\bfseries 1. }\setlength {\cftsectionindent }{\cftchapternumwidth }
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}First chapter}{5}
\settowidth {\cftsectionnumwidth }{\normalfont 1.1. }\setlength {\cftsubsectionindent }{\dimexpr \cftsectionnumwidth +\cftsectionindent }
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}First section long long long long long long long long long long long long title}{5}
\settowidth {\cftsubsectionnumwidth }{\normalfont 1.1.1. }\setlength {\cftsubsubsectionindent }{\dimexpr \cftsubsectionnumwidth +\cftsubsectionindent }
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}First subsection long long long long long long long long long long long long title}{5}
\settowidth {\cftchapternumwidth }{\bfseries 12. }\setlength {\cftsectionindent }{\cftchapternumwidth }
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {12}Another chapter long long long long long long long long long long long long title}{7}
\settowidth {\cftsectionnumwidth }{\normalfont 12.1. }\setlength {\cftsubsectionindent }{\dimexpr \cftsectionnumwidth +\cftsectionindent }
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {12.1}First section long long long long long long long long long long long long title}{7}
\settowidth {\cftsubsectionnumwidth }{\normalfont 12.1.1. }\setlength {\cftsubsubsectionindent }{\dimexpr \cftsubsectionnumwidth +\cftsubsectionindent }
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {12.1.1}First subsection long long long long long long long long long long long long title}{7}
\contentsline {subsection}{Short conclusion}{7}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. The decision holds all other settings of `memoir`. This seems to be very nice feature of your approach. However your answer was submitted a litle bit later than @jfbu's answer. The bounty is going to be given to @jfbu.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: Timing has nothing to do with the awarding of a bounty to someone. The award is given based on whatever *you* decide to be the case.

Comment: I would be very grateful for your help with `UPD2`:  I've tried to set `\hphantom{1.\space}` before first section in Introduction, but the attempt to set`\setlength {\cftsubsectionindent}{...}` failed.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: I get this output when using my method with a section under `Introduction`: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQiq8.png). That is, the output is as expected with the correct indentation. Are you using my method?

Comment: yes, with one extra line to make chapter font `\normalfont` (not bold): `\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{}` This command adds small indent, which makes ToC uneven.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: The problem here is that `\chapter*` doesn't write anything to the ToC - not even with my patch. So, you'll have to either insert it (the spacing adjustment) manually like you do the ToC-entry for `Introduction`, or you can patch a sub-component within `\chapter*` called `\@m@mschapter`. This requires [`xpatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) instead of [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). [Here is a MWE](https://pastebin.com/PMDw494P) that produces this output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/424Fa.png).

Comment: I'll put the notice about your help in my book template.  It works! I've updated the question to write this important information.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you want.

**Edited** to add `\bfseries` in the box serving to compute needed width for numbers of chapters. (I briefly looked if some memoir macro was available to set this style, but did not find immediately, so simply adding `\bfseries`.)

Also the edit corrects the typo from OP regarding the final unnumbered subsection.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%% enumeration levels in the ToC and text
%\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil} %hyphenation is forbidden

\usepackage{etoc}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
             {\edef\defaultchapternumwidth{\the\cftchapternumwidth}}
             {\etocifnumbered
               {\settowidth{\cftchapternumwidth}{\bfseries\etocnumber.\space}}%
               {\cftchapternumwidth\defaultchapternumwidth\relax}}
             {\etocsavedchaptertocline
               {\etocifnumbered
                 {\chapternumberline{\etocnumber.}}
                 {}%
                \etocname}{\etocpage}}
             {}%
\etocsetstyle{section}
             {\cftsectionindent\cftchapternumwidth
              \edef\defaultsectionnumwidth{\the\cftsectionnumwidth}}
             {\etocifnumbered
               {\settowidth{\cftsectionnumwidth}{\etocnumber.\space}}%
               {\cftsectionnumwidth\defaultsectionnumwidth\relax}}
             {\etocsavedsectiontocline
               {\etocifnumbered
                 {\numberline{\etocnumber.}}
                 {}%
                 \etocname}{\etocpage}}
             {}%
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
             {\cftsubsectionindent\cftsectionindent
              \advance\cftsubsectionindent\cftsectionnumwidth
              \edef\defaultsubsectionnumwidth{\the\cftsubsectionnumwidth}}
             {\etocifnumbered
               {\settowidth{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{\etocnumber.\space}}%
               {\cftsubsectionnumwidth\defaultsubsectionnumwidth\relax}}
             {\etocsavedsubsectiontocline
               {\etocifnumbered
                 {\numberline{\etocnumber.}}
                 {}%
                 \etocname}{\etocpage}}
             {}%

\begin{document}

\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Another chapter long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection*{Short conclusion with long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Short conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need `etoc 1.08k` or later (due to `\etocsavedchaptertocline` etc.. macros).

Notice that the above uses the OP's `\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil} %hyphenation is forbidden` for better or worse.

Updated image (after `\bseries` addition, and the final unnumbered `subsection`).

[image]

For subsubsection, one can add the following code, which is similar to the other toc styles:

```
\etocsetstyle{subsubsection}
             {\cftsubsubsectionindent\cftsubsectionindent
              \advance\cftsubsubsectionindent\cftsubsectionnumwidth
              \edef\defaultsubsubsectionnumwidth{\the\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}}
             {\etocifnumbered
               {\settowidth{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}{\etocnumber.\space}}%
               {\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth\defaultsubsubsectionnumwidth\relax}}
             {\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline
               {\etocifnumbered
                 {\numberline{\etocnumber.}}
                 {}%
                 \etocname}{\etocpage}}
             {}%
```

This needs that the tocdepth allows the subsubsections to actually show. `etoc` allows a global setting which allows subsubsections entries in the `.toc` file, but with `\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsection}` for example they will actually be ignored in current TOC.

I make two remarks:

- one advantage is that you may do another `\tableofcontents` elsewhere in the document with another style; or you can use `etoc`'s `\localtableofcontents`. As no extra information was inserted in the `.toc` file, you are free to either follow similar method or use other style for other TOCs. And another `\tableofcontents` can use the memoir default (`\etocstandardlines` tells etoc to be transparent).
- attention with this style with mixing non-numbered entries with numbered ones. As it stands, the non-numbered entries (added using `\addcontentsline`) will use the default widths set-up by `memoir`. Say a non-numbered section: then the indent of subsections will be a bit different than the indent of subsections of another numbered section (and numbered sections may themselves differ say if `9` versus `10`). One can always make the code more sophisticated, for example non-numbered sections would use the width appropriate for section number `1`.

---

Well, in response to

```
UDT2

The 0.1 subsection in Introduction should be indented as the 1.1 subsection.
```

which precisely relates to my remark above, and in view of the generous bounty, I indicate before bedtime that

```
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
             {}
             {\etocifnumbered
               {\settowidth{\cftchapternumwidth}{\bfseries\etocnumber.\space}}%
               {\settowidth{\cftchapternumwidth}{\bfseries1.\space}}}
             {\etocsavedchaptertocline
               {\etocifnumbered
                 {\chapternumberline{\etocnumber.}}
                 {}%
                \etocname}{\etocpage}}
             {}%
```

does the trick:

[image]

(the above image using `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{\medskipamount}`)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.  The result has one-to-one correspondence to the problem setting. Moreover this result can be useful for classes, which differ from `memoir`. I've decided to split the prize between your answer and the answer given by Werner.

Comment: for `10%` more I can post  the `subsubsection` code... I will even post `paragraph` for `20%` more! `;-)`

Comment: I posted `subsubsection` code ...

Comment: special gratitude for `subsubsection` code! =) To be serious, it is interesting how to delete the blank `newline`  after `chapter block`.

Comment: `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}` seems the way for that. It looks a bit tight, but you can use something like `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{\smallskipamount}`. I would use `\medskipamount`.

Comment: very simple, the command is the same as the similar in the settings of `memoir`. Moreover `etoc` can overwrite some settings of memoir if the appropriate commands are the last. I've one problem now. It is given in `UPD2`: how to set the indent for subsection 0.1 from Introduction as 1.1 from Chapter 1?

Comment: see update answer, spakoïni nochtou

Comment: hope, that the last (morning) question. I use 2 contents. First, standard is called `toc` and the extra one called `tec`. I wrapped all `etoc`commands by `makeatletter...\makeatother`, however `tec` is formatted only by `memoir` native commands. How can I apply the `etoc` settings to the `tec`? The second content is created as simplified version of this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170912/contents-page-in-two-different-languages

Comment: Looking  at your link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170912/contents-page-in-two-different-languages, `etoc` can very well handle that with only one `toc` file. I will add an answer to that question, perhaps it will be enough for you.

Comment: I slightly hack `\tableofcontents` and `\frenchtableofcontents` to delete unexpected new line in the following way: `\renewcommand\tableofcontents{ \chapter*{%
  \normalfont\MakeUppercase{Content} }%
  \vspace*{-1\curtextsize} %delete unexpected \f@size pt \@starttoc{toc} }`

Comment: I correct my comment above, using only one file for multi-lingual tocs is complicated due to the fact that Babel adds commands to the toc file which pertubates the thing. If you have solved your problem ok, if not ask precise separate question.

Comment: thank you for the conversation. If there is a need, we'll start new question.